# Unity VR: Lagging 360 Video Playback in Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I'm developing a Unity VR game that utilizes 360 videos, featuring distinct perspectives for a worker and a driver. The driver's videos have been edited to primarily showcase the steering wheel and the front window. While testing within Unity's Playmode, both sets of videos play smoothly without any issues, including when using a VR headset.

However, upon building the game, I encountered a problem where the worker's videos continue to play as expected, but the video playback for the driver's edited videos experiences significant lag.

To address this, I attempted to adjust the display refresh rate specifically for Oculus devices with the following code, hoping it might alleviate the lag:

```
Unity.XR.Oculus.Performance.TrySetDisplayRefreshRate(90f);
```

Unfortunately, this adjustment did not result in any noticeable improvement. I've provided a link to the recorded footage to better illustrate the issue: https://imgur.com/a/WuqpEqE

Any suggestions on optimization techniques or adjustments to Unity or Oculus settings that could improve the performance of heavily edited 360 videos would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one set of videos is lagging while the other one is not, with the same video player, your files will be different.
Inspect them with VLC, I would suspect one of them is coded that hardware decodes on the Quest while the other is not. I have often encountered H265 being delivered for example.

That or the bitrate is wildly different. VLC will help you to find out both. Adjusting the refresh rate is not the correct way to go about this.

Comment: They are both H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1). The difference is only in the resolution and fps, but I think that30 fps should also be fine. Here is more information https://imgur.com/a/zpAbwhf if you can hint me where the problem could be, that would be great

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you. As you marked it as the answer, what was different between them in the end?

Comment: In the end I had to purchase the Premium version of the software that I edited the videos. Then, I could export them as H265 as it was only a premium feature, but this indeed was my problem.

Comment: Great that you fond a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Vulkan Renderer instead of OpenGl when packaging? It is a known issue for video playback on Vulkan, the playback will lag.

Switching to OpenGL will fix this issue.